# iOS detect user modifying device clock time

Tags: ios, swift

My App requires correct time (can not rely on device time since the user can change it + carrier might be not available or doesnt support APIWorldClock). Initially I use http calls to a trusted server, however there are situations when network is not available.

Is there any other option I can use?

Can I rely on API World Clock to detect that the user modified the device clock? Does my app always need to be running in order to get this notification (this I would like to avoid)?

Comment: This becomes more of a philosophical question. How can a device disconnected from the rest of the world, and with an untrustworthy user, have any idea what the *actual* time is? What is time, anyway? It's subjective. What if the user sets a "bad" time while your app is stopped, or before your software is installed?

Comment: You can't detect time being advanced, but if you periodically store the current time you can detect the clock going backwards and assume that the user has reset the clock.